# Using wireless relay for guitar causes buzz in all my amps

Tags: guitar-effects

I use a Line 6 wireless system with my guitars, but have found that they cause a constant buzz from the amp.  I can eliminate this if I plug directly into the amp with a traditional instrument cable.  How can I remove or reduce the buzz from the wireless system?

Comment: This happens with any amp I use.

Comment: Assuming you are using a Line 6 Wireless unit, with a transmitter at the guitar and a receiver at the amp, you should check the cable from the receiver into the amp.  Other than that I would suspect that the unit isn't working correctly, and may be broken.

Comment: Yes, it is a Line 6 wireless unit, and I have several, which all do the same thing.  The amps handle direct cord connection without a buzz, but when I use any of the cordless pickups (and a couple have been fixed by a local trusted shop and should work perfectly), there is a buzz, probably the worst when I use my Boss Katana 100 amp.

Comment: Why would one buy several if you don't have one working yet?  Contact line6 for support.

Comment: This is a fault with something in your system. I have used Line6 wireless units as well as many others. None should have much interference or buzz.

Answer (score 1):

Often a player will position the receiver of a wireless unit on top of the amp they're using making it susceptible to picking up the hum that may be originating in the power transformer of the amp. If this is the case, the solution will be to relocate the receiver far enough away from the amp to eliminate the hum. usually just a few inches will do the trick.

Comment: The Line 6 receiver is always positioned on the floor a few feet from the amp.  The buzz happens when I use the cordless receive/transmitter with any of the amps I own or have tried.  Is there not a product made to correct this problem?  It seems like it should be a problem that others have had as well.